# Non resource deadlock?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, resources, operating-system, deadlock

I've gotten a question from my professor in operating systems that reads "Explain non resource deadlocks", and I haven't got a clue what I'm supposed to answer!

Doesn't a deadlock require some kind of resource to hog to be considered an actual deadlock?

If any of you have any suggestion to what he might have in mind, please reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have scenarios where you don't have any resources.

Say you have two nodes in a network that communicate and have a 3 steps handshake:

- *node1* sends a message to *node2* and **waits for a response**
- *node2* receives the message and sends back the response to *node1* and **waits**
- but the **response is lost** on the network due to a temporary disruption

Both nodes are waiting for each other => **deadlock**

Comment: This is really helpful! I never thought about it from a network point of view. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the above answer can yet be illustrated with `response` and `ack` messages *as resources*:

- *response* is being held by *node2* because of a network partition
- *ack* is being held by *node1* because of no response is got

[image]