# Laravel how to prevent concurrent handling of requests sent by same user

Tags: php, database, laravel, concurrency

I have following controller method that creates a new order if and only if the there are no opened orders (opened order has **status** = 0, closed order has **status** = 1).

```
public function createOrder(Request $req){
    // some validation stuff
    $last_active = Orders::where('user_id', $this->user->id)->where('status', 0)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
    if ($last_active){
        return ['status' => 'error'];
    }
    $order= Orders::create([
        'status' => 0
                // some details
        ]);
    return ['status' => 'success'];
}
```

This method is bound to particular route

```
Route::post('/create', 'OrderController@create');
```

Client makes an ajax requests to this route.
Logic behind this is super simple: i want user to have only one active order at time, so user must do some actions to close previous order before creating new one. 
Following code works perfectly in case of normal user, but it does not in case of user that wants to harm my application.
So here is the problem. When user sends tons of such requests per second (i do it just within Google Chrome dev console with following script)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
                url : '/create',
                type : 'post', 
            success: function(d){
                console.log(d)
            }
        })
}, 1);
```

It causes multiple records with **status**=0 inserted into database when expected only one to be inserted, and others should not. 
IMO, what happens is:

1. Many requests touch webserver (nginx in my case)
2. Webserver creates many PHP processes (via php-fpm in my case)
3. Multiple PHP processes run method at the same time, passing **if ($last_active){...}** check simultaneously before some record is inserted in another process, thus resulting in multiple records inserted.

What i tried to fix this:

1. On nginx side, i limit request rate (10 r/s). This does not help a lot, because it still allows to send 10 requests very fast, with super small delay between them, before rejecting them. I can not set rate limit value lower than 10 r/s because it will hurt normal users
2. On laravel side, i tried to make a transaction

```
public function createOrder(Request $req){
    // some validation stuff
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try{
        $last_active = Orders::where('user_id', $this->user->id)->where('status', 0)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
        if ($last_active){
            DB::rollBack();  // i dont think i even need this
            return ['status' => 'error'];
        }
        $order= Orders::create([
            'status' => 0
                    // some details
            ]);
        DB::commit();
    }
    catch (\Exception $e){
        DB::rollBack();
        return ['status' => 'error'];
    }
    return ['status' => 'success'];
}
```

Using transaction significantly reduces number of rows inserted (and often even works as intended - allowing only 1 row to be inserted, but not always).

3. I created a middleware which keeps track of when last user request was maden and stores this information in session

```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ((session()->has('last_request_time') && (microtime(true) - session()->get('last_request_time')) > 1)
            || !session()->has('last_request_time')){
            session()->put('last_request_time', microtime(true));
            return $next($request);
        }
       return abort(429);
    }
```

It did not help at all, because it just moves problem on the middleware level

4. I also tried something odd:

```
public function createOrder(Request $req){
    if (Cache::has('action.' . $this->user->id)) return ['status' => 'error'];
        Cache::put('action.' . $this->user->id, '', 0.5);
    // some validation stuff
    $last_active = Orders::where('user_id', $this->user->id)->where('status', 0)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
    if ($last_active){
        Cache::forget('action.' . $this->user->id);
        return ['status' => 'error'];
    }
    $order= Orders::create([
        'status' => 0
                // some details
        ]);
    Cache::forget('action.' . $this->user->id);
    return ['status' => 'success'];
}
```

This kind of works in many cases, especially combined with transaction, but sometimes it still allows up to 2 rows to be inserted  (in 1-2 cases out of 30). And also it does look weird for me.
I thought about queues, but as laravel doc states they are intented for time consuming tasks. Also i thought about table locking, but is also seems weird and perfomance affecting for normal users. 
I believe that there exist clean and simple solution for this problem, but i can not find nothing reasonable in google, maybe i am missing something super obvious? Can you help please?
Also, there are so many similar cases in my application that i really want to find some general solution for situations where concurrent execution causes such bugs not only with database, but also sessions, cache, redis, etc.

Comment: I don't think this `$last_active = Orders::where('user_id', $this->user->id)->where('status', 0)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();` will return exactly the last user's order. How I read it it will return last that has zero status. It is not previous order necessarily. If you want to check status of last order it should be `$order = Order::where(['user_id' => $this->user->id])->latest()->first(); if ($order && (1 === $order->status)) {/** Exception */}`

Comment: Yea, i rather want to check whether there exist some non-closed order and obtain it, not just check whether last order was closed. I tried your code though and it did not work either, because at the moment of checking `if ($order && (1 === $order->status))` multiple processes pass this check simultaneously and all of them are able to insert a new record

Comment: Saying because you emphasized "previous order" as singular. In this case you are telling now, inverse search logic: `$order = Order::where(['user' => $this->user->id, 'status' => 1])->first(); if ($order) {throw new \Exception("Case of existing order with status 1.")} /** rest of code */`. I wasn't trying to solve issue but more likely I was trying to connect code, description, error and intention. Have you tried @levi 's proposal?

Comment: Thanks for pointing, changed the statement. @levi totally saved my day, it worked just perfect with small change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use `lockForUpdate()` on the `user` model, to prevent concurrent orders from being inserted by same user:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
User::where('id', $this->user->id)->lockForUpdate()->first();
// Create order if not exists etc...
DB::commit();
```

Comment: That is brilliant idea, thanks. It did not work with just `$this->user->lockForUpdate();` because it seems to not producing any sql query, but `$u = User::where('id', $this->user->id)->lockForUpdate()->first();` did work as charm. So as far as i understand, lockForUpdate prevents user row to be selected until the whole transaction commits, so other transactions will have to wait. I am not really into database locking, can you please explain in which cases this trick can cause a deadlock and is it even possible if i only lock single user and do not lock anything else in database?

Comment: Given that there is only a single resource lock associated with this transaction, it should not result in a deadlock. See here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058542/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-deadlock-with-single-lock